# MouseListener does nothing

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

So I wrote this code in java. It should print "Mouse Click" when I press mouse button, but it does nothing.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class mainPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    List<Integer> listLoc;
    List<ImageIcon> listImg;

    ImageIcon objPpc;
    ImageIcon ttlSpace;

    public mainPanel(){
        loadImg();
        fillBck(ttlSpace);
        addTtl(objPpc, 1);
        repaint();
    }

    public void fillBck(ImageIcon fillingImg){
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            addTtl(fillingImg, i);
        }
    }

    public void loadImg(){
        objPpc = new ImageIcon ("img/obj/ppcBuild1.png");
        ttlSpace = new ImageIcon ("img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png");
        listLoc = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listImg = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
    }

    public void addTtl(ImageIcon addedImg, int addedLoc){

        System.out.println("----- addTtl -----");
        System.out.println(addedImg);
        listImg.add(addedImg);
        System.out.println(addedLoc);
        listLoc.add(addedLoc);
        System.out.println("----- /addTtl -----");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < listImg.size(); i ++) {
            g.drawImage((listImg.get(i)).getImage(), (listLoc.get(i) * (this.getWidth() / 16)), 0, (this.getWidth() / 16) , this.getHeight(), null);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Mouse Click");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The java console only prints this, and no error codes:

```
----- addTtl -----

img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
0
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
1
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
2
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
3
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
4
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
5
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
6
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
7
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
8
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
9
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
10
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
11
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
12
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
13
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
14
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/ttl/spaceBuild1.png
15
----- /addTtl -----

----- addTtl -----
img/obj/ppcBuild1.png
1
----- /addTtl -----
```

When I press any mouse button (even wheel[MOUSE3]) on screen, it does nothing.

How could I fix that?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: btw, in Swing the method to override for custom painting is paintComponent (_not_ paint)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code never adds any MouseListener to the panel. You should have this line somewhere:

```
this.addMouseListener(this);
```

When you implement MouseListener, that means that you're **able** to listen to mouse events. To actually listen to mouse events, the listener must be added (registered) to some component that produces mouse events.

Answer (score 3):

You need to register mouseListener add

```
addMouseListener(this);
```

**Also See**

- [Mouse Listener Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)